# c# check->create->check folder loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, backup, directory, file-exists

I want ask an easy question about my code in c# .... I know that there are lot of topics with same or similar topic/code result. But I need to hand in my code to school, so I can't just use the best solution on Stackoverflow or another page. I showed my code to my teacher and now need to fix a little bug.

The Code is about backing up files with a console report, so in first step I check if a folder exists. Second step is to report that the folder exists or doesn't exist, if it doesn't the code creates this folder and rechecks ...

```
SITUATION : CONSOLE REPORT

folders doesnt exist:
02:02:06 directory for backup Exist ... can continue
02:02:05 directory for backup DOESNT EXIST ... creating required folders...

folders exist :
02:02:55 directory for backup Exist ... can continue
02:02:54 directory for backup Exist ... can continue
```

In the 1st example the report is OK, but in the 2nd, my code tells me the same information twice... i just can't get my code to work properly..

Here is my code:

```
    public void checkbackupfolders() {
       do {
            create_backup_folders();
          } while (create_backup_folders() == false);
    }

    public bool create_backup_folders()
    {
        string path = "\\BACKUP\\" + Globals.hostname;
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            consolecho("directory for backup Exist ... can continue");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            consolecho("directory for backup DOESNT EXIST ... creating required folders...");
            Directory.CreateDirectory("\\BACKUP\\" + Globals.hostname);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling the method *twice* here?:

```
do {
    create_backup_folders();
} while (create_backup_folders() == false);
```

That's going to make things confusing, as you're now discovering.  Just call the method *once* on each loop iteration and store the result of the method.  Then use that stored result in the loop condition:

```
var canContinue = false;
do {
    canContinue = create_backup_folders();
} while (canContinue == false);
```

Comment: Definitely your suggestion look nicer. It still very unclear why even have a loop - `CreateDirectory` can't half-succeed, so calling it once should be enough (especially since it will create all necessary sub-folders too)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: True, this entire block of code seems a bit silly.  Though perhaps that has something to do with `"so i cant use the best solution"`, which is a statement I can't quite wrap my head around :-/

Comment: thy david, there are lot of solutions what I must llearn before publish my first usable soft :)